# LIKE query with a varying number of LIKE’s

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

My current test revolves around a hypothetical database consisting of a `PERSON` table populated with their details.

I can undertake a simple `LIKE` query were I return the details of say a person or persons named `Tom`.

My question is how can I build a query were there may be multiple names and return their details?

I my exercise there is a checkbox list of names and I need to return the details for all those I select?

[image: See Image]

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: `WHERE name IN ('Joe', 'Zoe', 'Dave')`

Comment: I'm curious why you mention `like`. Do you actually need the ability to specify wildcards and such, or is it only exact matches you care about? If the latter, then this is simple standard SQL as mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response and my use of LIKE in this situation just shows I still have a long way to go as wildcards are not required. Regarding IN ('Joe', 'Steve', 'John') it wouldn't be practical to hard code every possible combination of selected names therefore how can this be done as a parameter/variable? I was also wondering how this could be done as a stored procedure?